# Does state as class requires SatefulWidget?

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I am trying to learn the bloc pattern in flutter and creating one sample app using `bloc` framework. The app is a counter and has two buttons beneth the counter text field. Upon clicking on the `True` and `False` button currently Ii am just incrementing and decrementing the counter respectively.

What I have noticed is, If I use class as a State while implementing `Bloc` pattern then I have to write `StatefulWidget`. Inversely, if I use `int` only then even using `StatelessWidget` works fine.

So, it confuses me while implementing the same sample, using class as state and primitive data type as state.

Here is my code `CounterBloc` code with state defined as class `CounterState`

```
enum CounterEvent { Increment, Decrement }

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterState counterState = new CounterState(counter: 0);
  @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  CounterState get initialState => counterState;

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState

    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.Decrement:
        counterState.decrementCounter();
        yield counterState;

        break;

      case CounterEvent.Increment:
        counterState.incrementCounter();
        yield counterState;

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

My `CounterState` is defined as follows

```
class CounterState {
  int counter = 0;

  CounterState({this.counter});

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
  }

  void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
  }
}
```

This is how I am dispatching event on button press

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    counterBloc.dispatch(CounterEvent.Increment);
  });
```

Binding with UI inside `StatefulWidget`

```
 BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
       .....
                child: Text(
                  snapshot.counter.toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),

     .....
 });
```

Now if i use the `int` as state then it works fine in `StatelessWidget`.

Here is the `CounterBloc` with state a integer

```
enum CounterEvent { Increment, Decrement }

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  int get initialState => 0;

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState

    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.Decrement:

        yield currentState -1;;

        break;

      case CounterEvent.Increment:

        yield currentState +1;;

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

```
enum CounterEvent { Increment, Decrement }

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  CounterState get initialState => CounterState(counter: 0);

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState

    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.Decrement:
        CounterState counterState = CounterState(counter: currentState.counter);
        counterState.decrementCounter();
        yield counterState;

        break;

      case CounterEvent.Increment:
        CounterState counterState = CounterState(counter: currentState.counter);
        counterState.incrementCounter();

        yield counterState;

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

have resolved the issue with the help of @Rémi Rousselet's comment. Now I am passing the new state everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not about whether it's a class or not, but about immutability.

Using `bloc`, your state must be immutable. You should not modify the previous state, but instead, create a new modified state.